# How do I make a div close when I click anywhere outside it?

Tags: jquery, html, events

I have a function that calls a `#notify` div.

When a user clicks on this div, the function is called.  Then when the user clicks again on that same div, the function is hidden (using toggle).

I was wondering how could I use this same function, but instead have an off click element so if the user off clicks, the div is hidden.

in short
when user clicks on div (small box) a function is called (a Big box appears underneath the small box) the only way to remove the big box is to click again on the small box. I want the big box to hide when the user clicks anywhere outside the big box.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var notify = $("#notify");
var notifyLink = $("#notify_link");
var result = $("#result");
var loader = $('#loader');
var count = $("#count");

notify.hide();
notify.click(function(event) {
    // Handle the click on the notify div so the document click doesn't close it
    event.stopPropagation();
});

notifyLink.click(

        function () { notify.toggle(notify.css('display') == 'none');
                loader.html('<?php echo elgg_view('ajax/loader',array('slashes' => true)); ?>');    
        result.load("<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/ajax/data.php",function(){
                        loader.empty(); // remove the loading gif

                    });    
        });

notifyLink.toggle(
     function () {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
  } );

     count.load("<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/ajax/livenum.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      count.load("<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/ajax/livenum.php");
   }, 2500);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="notify_link">&nbsp;</a><span id="count"></span>


<div id="notify" style="display:none;">
<h4>Notifications</h4>
<div id="loader"></div>
    <div id="result" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
    <div class="seeall"><a href="<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/all.php">See All Notifications</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML body as well?  And I am confused about what you're asking, could you elaborate on "have an off click element so if the user off clicks the div is hidden"?

Comment: when user clicks on div (small box) a funtion is called (a Big box appears underneath the small box) the only way to remove the big box is to click again on the small box.  I want the big box to hide when the user clicks anywhere outside the big box.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Formatted the code so it was more readable.  Had to go through multiple passes as the jsbeautifier wasn't ignoring the `'` marks embedded in the php tag.

Comment: Marking as a favorite and will check this out later.  Let me know if you solve this on your own before I reply back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the big box to hide when the user clicks anywhere outside the big box.

You'll need to do a few things when the `#notify_link` div is clicked:

- Enable a click on the `document` to hide the `#notify` div
- Keep the `#notify_link` div click from bleeding through to the `document` and immediately closing the `#notify` div.  You can do this with `event.stopPropagation()`
- Disable the click on the `#notify_link` div after it has been clicked, so it doesn't override the new `document` click handler
- In the `document` click handler, reset everything to how it was before the `#notify` div was displayed

[Here's a fiddle demonstrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/M6fcG/).

And here's the sample code.  I only loosely based it on your existing code, so you'll have to merge the two solutions together.

---

Edit:

You mentioned in comments you're having trouble combining the code.  I don't have your HTML/PHP to work with, but this is what I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var notify = $("#notify");
    notify.hide();
    notify.click(function(event) {
        // Handle the click on the notify div so the document click doesn't close it
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    var notifyLink = $("#notify_link");
    notifyLink.click(showNotification);

    function showNotification(event) {
        $(this).unbind('click', showNotification);

        $(this).addClass("selected");
        loadData();

        notify.show();

        $(document).click(hideNotification);

        // So the document doesn't immediately handle this same click event
        event.stopPropagation();
    };

    function hideNotification(event) {
        $(this).unbind('click', hideNotification);

        notify.hide();
        $(this).removeClass("selected");

        notifyLink.click(showNotification);
    }

    $("#count").load(
        "<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/ajax/livenum.php"
    );
    var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
        $("#count").load(
            "<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/ajax/livenum.php"
        );
    }, 2500);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
});

function loadData() {
    $('#loader').html(
        '<?php echo elgg_view('ajax/loader',array('slashes' => true)); ?>'
    );
    $("#result").load(
        "<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>mod/notifications/ajax/data.php",
        function () {
            $('#loader').empty(); // remove the loading gif
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly right and your example works perfectly.  Now how to incorporate it in my code...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but Ive been at it for hours and I cant get it to play well with my code.  Can you tell me where in your code I need to insert mine?  Thanks again.

Comment: @StuartSloan: I'm hiding notify, so you can remove that line of your code.  I'd move the load code into its own function, and call that function in `showNotification`.  I'd split up the `notifyLink.toggle code and put half inside each function.  The rest can just stay where it is.

Comment: @StuartSloan: If you can provide some stripped down *example* HTML (not the real thing), then I can help you integrate the code completely.  I need to know where all the divs are in relation to each other, and I need *some* sort of contents for each div/load function.  You can clean up and fake what you need to.

Comment: I have no HTML I only have php.

Comment: I can post related php files.

Comment: @StuartSloan: What is the browser rendering then?  JavaScript sees HTML, not PHP.  PHP expands to HTML on the server side before being sent to client.  But posting anything you've got would help :)

Comment: @Marlyn yes you are right.  I got a little confused.  Ive added the full page to the code above.

Comment: @StuartSloan: I added code below that merges your code and mine.  Please give it a shot and let me know how it turns out.

Comment: @Marlyn YOU ARE GOOD!!!  No wonder you have so much rep points.  I'm new to this site and I'm already blown away with how friendly people are and how helpful you have been.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Marlyn I have a question. All works great except I have a notify_link and a notify_link .selected (DIV's).  When user clicks notify_link (gray button) the notification box comes up and notify_link .selected (same button just white) changes to white.  When the user off clicks the notification box goes away (thanks to you) but the notify_link .selected (white button) stays white.  Is there a way to reset it to notify_link (gray button)?  thanks for your help and i know this is above and beyond my original question.

Comment: It's pretty simple, I screwed up the code that `.removeClass`.  I ran it against `$(this)` in the `hideNotification` handler, but inside that handler `$(this)` means the **`document`**, not the `notify_link`.  Check out [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeNwS/8/) which shows demos of all the stuff.  You'll need to switch all your loads and PHP expands back because I was trying to get everything working on jsfiddle.  Don't worry about pulling me in for more on this one.  An upvote would be nice tho, lol :)

Comment: @Marlyn That was it!  You are good.  thank you for all your help.  I tried to give you an up vote but the site said that only level 15 and up can vote.  As soon as I am, you got my vote.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Marlyn works perfect.  If you would like to see what your code helped me to do, you should take a look at my site [www.fakepals.com](http://www.fakepals.com)  thanks again.

Comment: @StuartSloan: Meh, don't worry about the vote.  Cool site :)  YW, no problem

Comment: @Marlyn When I add "count.click(showNotification);" To the click function below I can click on the "count" div and I see the notify box come up just fine but it doesn't add $(this).addClass("selected"); like it does when I click on the "notifylink" div.

Comment: var count = $("#count");
    var notifyLink = $("#notify_link");

    count.click(showNotification);
    notifyLink.click(showNotification);

    function showNotification(event) {
        $(this).unbind('click', showNotification);
        
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        loadData();

        notify.show();

        $(document).click(hideNotification);

        // So the document doesn't immediately handle this same click event
        event.stopPropagation();
    };

Comment: @StuartSloan: Might be time to open a new question?  Not that I mind sticking around to help out, but the fact that you have to cram that code into comments shows that it might be time to put this specific question to bed.  Feel free to link to the new one once you get it posted and I'll take a look :)  Unless you think it is strongly related.  I can't tell without pulling it out of that comment and reformatting it...

Comment: lol Yeah I think your right.  I'll keep working it and I just wanna say thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @StuartSloan: Plus if you open another question, you could raise your rep a bit.  Once you get higher rep (20 required) then I could open a chat and we could keep plugging away at this problem.  I think it has better code support than the commenting system does.

Comment: I said Id give you a vote up when I was at a high enough rank, well i am now so I gave you a vote up.  thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

u can try a jquery selector

```
$('*:not(.bigbox)').click(function() {
  //do stuff.. hide the box?
});
```

Comment: That's WAY more processor intensive than it needs to be, check out `.delegate()` or `.on()`

Comment: my point is that your example runs through the entire DOM looking for everything that doesn't have the class `bigbox`, and binds a evenListener to _each_ of them; and that that is terribly unnecessary.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid it might work [if every element in the big box had that class], but it's *terrible* practice (i.e. "Not Useful")